# avoid copy by value when initializing reference

Tags: c++, default-copy-constructor, return-by-reference

I have a function interface:

```
struct iFace {
  virtual Type& getType() = 0;
}
```

and the idea is to retrieve it like:

```
iFace& iface = getIface();
Type& type = iface.getType();
```

however, i occassionally i do a mistake and write:

```
Type type = iface.getType();
```

which copies by value, which is what i want to avoid. However when i make such mistakes, the compiler doesn't issue a warning because its legal syntax. I would like to trigger a compile-time error for this, **Question** what are my alternatives?

i thought about declaring a copy constructor but not defining it anywhere, causing a link-time error if it's used, but then i won't be able to use copy constructor in **ANY** situation, which is less than desiderable

Comment: You can't really have it both ways.

Comment: that is what i'm afraid, so i thought asking it here to confirm. thanks for confirming it

Comment: It depends on what Type is.  If you can make Type abstract, then you will not be able to create an instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make iFace noncopyable by putting the copy constructor and assignment operator under "private". Then provide an explicit Copy method.

```
class Type {
public:
  virtual Copy(Type& dest) = 0;
private:
  Type (const Type &) {assert(false)}
  Type & operator=(const Type &)  {assert(false)}
}
```

You can also use [boost noncopyable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/noncopyable.hpp) to do the same thing (its implemented as above).

So if you wanted your code to copy, you would do

```
Type& type = iface.getType();
Type typeCpy;
type.Copy(typeCpy);
```

As an aside -- I'd add that if you're doing this because of performance concerns, are you certain the optimizer doesn't get rid of the temporary copy for you?

Comment: this falls under the case of copy-constructor becoming less useable. Lets keep this as the plan "if everything else fails"

Comment: @lurscher, you can also provide an explicit copy, see my edit.

Comment: can we use the explicit keyword to restrict copy constructors?

Comment: i'm not certain that the optimizer does any related optimizations. I'm just concerned with writing the code in the cleanest way possible which holds the assumptions. An important assumption in this case is that i always return values by reference

Answer (score -1):

Returning a pointer seems reasonable here, but if confusing ownership worries you you could return a wrapper around the reference.

```
struct Class {
    struct Ref {
        Ref(Class& c_) : c(c_) { }
        Class Clone() { return c; }
        // overload -> to provide access to c
      private:
        Class& c;
    };
};
```

The original class can copy as normal, but the reference you have to do explicitely. I'm not enthusiastic about the idea (I would think less of a user who didn't realize how copy semantics work than one who accidently held onto one of these too long) but theoretically it is doable.